# Orbeon Form Builder - Setting service value to label

Tags: orbeon

I have created a HTTP service, and it passes no parameters, and when the service is tested I get correct results as below [image]

Now I want to add this result I get from the service to a label control in my Orbeon form, could I please know how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "add this result I get from the service to a label control"? Are you saying that you'd like to use the result of the service to change the label of a control (i.e. instead of its value)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to use the result of the web service to appear on my label control.

Comment: Unfortunately right now control labels are not dynamic. It's not possible to do it with the HTTP Service Editor.

Comment: I see, okay... Thank you @ebruchez